# All Apps activity failes to load android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating an android app drawer, but it fails when i call the activity. Seems like it's something wrong on line 39. 
It looks something like a NullPointerException.
Could you please help me?

Java code:

```
package com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.mobile;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity {
LinearLayout appsLinearLayout;
ListView list;
Intent intent;
private ArrayList<ResolveInfo> mApplicationList;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.allapps_screen);
    //Import views
    appsLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.appsLinearLayout);

    //Set wallpaper
    appsLinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);

    //Load all apps
    final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =
            (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
    {

        Log.i("TAG", ": Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.
                applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.
                    applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                ((TextView)convertView).setText(text);
                return convertView;
            }
        };
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    final ActivityInfo info = mApplicationList.get(position).activityInfo;
    intent.setClassName(info.packageName, info.name);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/appsLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Apps"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="35dp" />


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="13dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/seperator" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.mobile/com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.mobile.AllAppsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4499)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:788)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:440)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at com.mysoftware.mysoftwareos.mobile.AllAppsActivity.onCreate(AllAppsActivity.java:39)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4637)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1051)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
01-27 01:35:24.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2150):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you highlight line 39 with a comment? The formatting might have changed the line number if we paste it ourselves.

Comment: your null pointer originates here: `ApplicationPackageManager.java:440`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, from this:

```
final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =
            (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

`intent` is still null, you haven't made an Intent Object.

I'm not sure what Intent you're trying to match against, but you still need to instantiate it using the `new` keyword before using it.

Eg

```
intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
```

**Also** from that same call, you are shadowing the global variable `list`. Either consider taking out

```
final ArrayList<ResolveInfo>
```

so you are working with the global `list` **or** remove that global reference.

Moving on, I don't thik `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` is a valid flag for [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), since this seems to be a result constant.

Lastly: `mApplicationList` is also not instantiated, but then you try to read from it. Now this may be set somewhere else, we don't have the whole code. This only affects the click on a List item.